# Independent circuits on a common trip CB

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, nec

Is it permissible under the 2014 NEC to feed two independent 120VAC branch circuits from a common trip (aka double pole) circuit breaker?  The circuits do *not* share a neutral wire, and are ordinary 20A branch circuits otherwise.

Comment: I'm not a code expert so I wont post an answer - but I would assume it is allowed.  If you have two independant circuits that share a junction box somewhere it would improve safety - since someone cant turn off just one of the curcuits feeding that box and still have the other energized.

Comment: Logically it wouldn't matter. Worse case it would be viewed as an inconvenience, where multi-wire circuits it's for safety; it ensures the shared neutral would have no imbalanced load on it. If they're not sharing the neutral I can't see why it would be an issue or even matter. Still on 2011 though so I won't answer. The only thing that stands out as an issue is if one of them is for some type of safety/alarm system.

Comment: ...but when you say common trip do you mean double pole/single throw? If so, they're intent is for 240V circuits but are functionally the same. So, going the other way is allowed. IOW, a two pole/double throw with a tie can be used in place of a two pole single throw provided it's rated 12/240; most are today.

Comment: One place where I'd question if it's allowed is where independent circuits are required by code. For example, in a kitchen, I believe two separate 20 amp outlet circuits are required; I'd question if these could be on a common throw breaker.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils -- yes, I do mean double pole when I say 'common trip'

Comment: But is it single throw (one lever) or double throw (two levers). There are 240V/2p that have a single lever which are rated 240 only. Then there's 120/240V/2p which have two levers. The code(2011) distinguishes between them and what circuits they *should* be used on. I doubt it matters but it might.

Comment: These breakers have two levers, tied together.